# How to install FlightGear - Flight Simulator

Tags: 12.04, games

Im trying to install FlightGear - Flight Simulator, from sourceforge.
 File: flightgear-3.4.0.tar.bz2
I extracted the tar.bz2 file it's now a file flightgear
I don't know what to do next? Im lost. I need help.
Thank You

Comment: If your problem not solved with my answer please add comment @Ronnie

Comment: feel free accept my answer if it solved your Q @RonnieMarlow =)

Comment: Please see my updater at ** https://askubuntu.com/questions/1471132/how-to-get-a-valid-set-of-data-files-for-flightgear-so-it-can-fully-launch **.  I tested it on my Ubuntu distribution and it works great!  If you have additional questions about the installation, please comment further.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/flightgear
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flightgear
```

The first command adds a PPA, the second command updates your packages list and the third command installs the application in an easy way.

Comment: I am happy I got a reply. But why add the ppa. Can I install it through the file?

Comment: Your problem solved ??.......refer [here](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-flightgear-3-0-on-ubuntu-14-0413-1012-1012-04-linux-mint-161413-and-elementary-os-0-2/)

Comment: If your goal is to compile the program yourself, then you can use the downloaded archive. But since you already fail, after the archive is extracted, you should use the PPA.

Comment: @Ravan :  the link answer **here** ( https://linuxg.net/how-to-install-flightgear-3-0-on-ubuntu-14-0413-1012-1012-04-linux-mint-161413-and-elementary-os-0-2/ )does not completely work.  Additional steps are required.  See    https://askubuntu.com/questions/1471132/how-to-get-a-valid-set-of-data-files-for-flightgear-so-it-can-fully-launch/1471193#1471193 for the solution I used to this problem.  I tested it and this solution works fine, both for the latest version as well as an older version of **flighgear** that is, by the above steps, is installed on my system.

Comment: Also check after each series of steps if (in Ubuntu), if ** flightgear ** (Flight Gear) is one of the options available at the bottom left software selection bar.  Sometimes, that is the only way to launch it easily.